# Making up detail view of TableViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitableview

I'm working on a project for iOS5 using xcode. 
ARC is ON
Using the storyboard

I have a class named **Event** which contains event info.
I have a TableView on the storyboard linked to my **ListViewController.m** file
I also made a view on the storyboard called 'Detail' and a **DetailViewController.m** file (which it is linked to)

Currently in my **ListViewController.m** I used this function:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
}
```

The items in the listview are made up from a var from the listviewcontroller, named events.

What I want to do is when I init the detailview, I want to pass the event coupled to that list item with it so I can fill up the text from the labels with the correct information in my **DetailViewController.m**.

I would like to do it like this cause I will also have other representations for the events (on a map, ...) and would like to use this detail view for all of them.

How to best set this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an 'Event' property on your 'DetailViewController' and assign it to the controller before doing the push:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Get here the selected event fron the datasource and assign it to yourSelectedEvent

    DetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];

    [detail setEvent: yourSelectedEvent];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
}
```

Then you can use it to put the text to the labels.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Apart from that, do you think this is a good way to implement what I want?

Comment: Theoretically, it's the way you should, talking about passing the Event reference. In the other hand, and it's just my opinion, you shouldn't use Storyboards for a "real" project... I mean, if these is not a learning project.

Comment: Owh? Why is storyboard something bad?

Comment: It's not a bad thing. It's a really helpful tool for mockups and for "drawing" the app flow, but you have to know certain things before you use it, even more for big or at least complex projects. I've found this, maybe can help too: http://bit.ly/OJmPPZ